# Oracle SQL REGEXP for finding a value between columns, irrespective of their position

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, regexp-like

I have following set of data in two different columns in a table. I need to check if the BB% value is matching between both the columns or not.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| BB12,AA13,CC24 | AA13,BB12,CC24 |
| BB99,AA34,CC78 | AA34,CC78,BB77 |
| AA22,BB33,CC77 | AA22,BB33,BB44,CC77 |

I initially tried using below REGEXP. But this will only work if the BB value in column A is always in position 1 and in Column B with position 2. But I need a REGEXP to check something for row 2 and row 3 scenarios.

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(ColumnA, '\w+', 1, 1) <> REGEXP_SUBSTR(ColumnB, '\w+', 1, 2)
```

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. But, it does not take account the case there are more than one occurrence of BBXXX in the columnA. In such a case, the comparison will only be based on the first occurence of BBXXX in the columnA.

```sql
with your_table (ColumnA, ColumnB) as (
select 'BB12,AA13,CC24',    'AA13,BB12,CC24' from dual union all
select 'BB99,AA34,CC78',    'AA34,CC78,BB77' from dual union all
select 'AA22,BB33,CC77',    'AA22,BB33,BB44,CC77' from dual union all
select 'AA22,BB33,CC77',    'AA22,BB44,BB33,CC77' from dual union all
select 'AA22,BB33,CC77',    'BB33,AA22,BB44,CC77' from dual
)
select COLUMNA, COLUMNB
from your_table t
where ','||COLUMNB||',' NOT like '%,'||regexp_substr(COLUMNA, 'BB[^,]*', 1, 1)||',%'
;
```

Comment: These REGEXP_SUBSTR( )'s only return the first occurrence of the pattern in the column.  If you swap BB33 and BB44 in row 3, row 3 will be returned also which is not what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your remark. You are correct. I made an update now to cover many other extra cases.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will do the trick and allow for the value in COLB to be in any position.  Return the rows where the first "BB" element in COLA is not in COLB. Note row 3 has the "BB" values swapped from the original example to show order does not matter.

```
WITH tbl(ID, cola, colb) AS (
  SELECT 1, 'BB12,AA13,CC24','AA13,BB12,CC24' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'BB99,AA34,CC78','AA34,CC78,BB77' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'AA22,BB33,CC77','AA22,BB44,BB33,CC77' FROM dual
)
SELECT ID, COLA, COLB
FROM tbl T
WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(COLB, REGEXP_SUBSTR(COLA, 'BB[^,]*'));


        ID COLA           COLB               
---------- -------------- -------------------
         2 BB99,AA34,CC78 AA34,CC78,BB77
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest extracting the BBxx substring from each string and then compare the two for equality or inequality:

```
WITH cteData(ColumnA,ColumnB) AS
  (SELECT 'BB12,AA13,CC24', 'AA13,BB12,CC24' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
   SELECT 'BB99,AA34,CC78', 'AA34,CC78,BB77' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
   SELECT 'AA22,BB33,CC77', 'AA22,BB33,BB44,CC77' FROM DUAL)
SELECT COLUMNA,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(COLUMNA, 'BB[^,]+') AS COLA_BB,
       COLUMNB,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(COLUMNB, 'BB[^,]+') AS COLB_BB
  FROM cteData
  WHERE REGEXP_SUBSTR(COLUMNA, 'BB[^,]+') = REGEXP_SUBSTR(COLUMNB, 'BB[^,]+')
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=62dfbb76749fe722eec55c92d50755cf)

Comment: If you switch BB44 and BB33 in the last row, columnB, it fails as the REGEXP_SUBSTR call only returns the first match.